# How to copy and paste without overwriting in Excel using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to paste a set of columns from one sheet to another. I want to paste the column WITHOUT deleting or overwriting on it. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this using vba.

```
Sub copy_data()


    If pass1 = 1 Then
        Sheets("I yr").Range(cellFrom1 & ":" & cellTo1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If
    
    If pass2 = 1 Then
        Sheets("II yr").Range(cellFrom2 & ":" & cellTo2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If
    
    If pass3 = 1 Then
        Sheets("III yr").Range(cellFrom3 & ":" & cellTo3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If
    
    If pass4 = 1 Then
        Sheets("IV yr").Range(cellFrom4 & ":" & cellTo4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If

 End Sub
```

When the second `IF` condition run and paste the column, the first `IF` condition columns are getting overwritten.

I want all columns, from all the if condition in `RANGE(B8, D40)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Sheets("I yr").Range(cellFrom1 & ":" & cellTo1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8")"

Comment: I have total of 4 copy pasting statements in my program. But each will be in seperate loops and executed one by one by one. All those loops will be pasting the value within the range (B8 to D40).so if my first loop paste the value. So when my second loop executed, the first loop pasted values are getting replaced with the second loop, i mean overwriting or deleting the first loop or before loop values in it and pasting the current values. So as final only my fourth loop values are only available in my sheet

Comment: I want to have all the values of all 4 loops in that range (B8 to D40) as final results

Comment: What would you want to happen if the cell that's being pasted into already has a value?  Not paste the value, add the value as a comma delimited list or something else?  Also can you post your code into your question rather than as a comment - the edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have updated the question

Comment: @hammed you want to move your destination range to the last row. There is a nice write up on this code here: https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-last-row/ I recommend adding a simple function to get the last row of a column and using it

Comment: @user1274820 - I have tried this, but the thing is ,in my "final" sheet after the range(B8:D40) where i need to paste the column, there will be other necessary rows with values ,so when I use "lastrow' it is pasting after the range I needed.

Comment: @user1274820 I want to paste all the loop values within the range(B8: D40)